# Could not load file or assembly CDO

Tags: c#, windows, windows-server-2008, cdo.message

I have .NET project which use CDO ActiveX. Everyhting works fine on Windows Server 2003 but when I move the project to Windows 2008 I get error below. Is this because CDO is not available on Windows 2008? How this could be solved?

```
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.CDO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format., 
StackTrace    at MailBotConsole.ServiceClass.ProcessEmail(String email)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `System.BadImageFormatException` occurs when a 64 bit assembly attempts to load a 32 bit assembly ( or vice versa ).  I'd guess that your move from 2003 -> 2008 also involved a change in architecture.  Make sure that your project matches the build target of the referenced assembly or try building as AnyCPU

Comment: My project is set to AnyCPU. I think the problem is that CDO does not exist anymore in Windows 2008.

Comment: I have tested again and it seems setting CPU compatibility to x86 solved the problem. Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when switching from a 32bit win xp environment to a windows 7 64 bit.  I wanted to provide my solution for anyone else that had a similar issue, spent hours before I figured this out.

I had read that I needed to switch my Active Solution Platform to build in x86 mode, but this didn't fix the problem.  Turns out I could leave my platform to any CPU and in my application pool under advanced settings ensure the .net framework was correct (in my case I had to switch it from 4.0 to 2.0) and I had to turn on "enable 32-bit applications" which was set to false.